# Migration to MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

I trying to migrate from MVC2 to MVC3. I use Spark view engine. After changing references I got only 2 errors in my Spark page base class:

```
The type 'System.Web.Mvc.IView' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. C:\Dev\main\app\Web\Html\SparkPageBase.cs


The type 'System.Web.Mvc.IViewDataContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    C:\Dev\main\app\Web\Html\SparkPageBase.cs
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try to download and use Spark View Engine for MVC3.

[Spark View Engine for MVC3](http://sparkviewengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/86901)

Answer (score 1):

See if it works after you modify the web.config to have the following version for `System.Web.Mvc`

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```